# Should I normalize variables after using Ordinal Encoder

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, categorical-encoding

I am working on some data that have some categorical variables with a cardinality of 3500.

So, I tried to use OrdinalEncoder to transform this column to a numerical column.

After that I applied Kmeans on the data to do some clustering.

My question is should I normalize the data after using the ordinal encoder and before passing it to the kmeans algorithm.

My current workflow :

1. Normalize numerical data
2. One hot encoding for variables with cardinality  < 10
3. Ordinal encoding for  variables with cardinality > 10
4. Kmeans algorithm

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you figure out the best approach for your probelm?